# AWS WAF Getting 403 forbidden error while trying to upload an image

Tags: amazon-web-services, xss, amazon-waf

We have enabled AWS WAF solution before my ALB and have SQL injection and XSS detection enabled. We have tried to setup a custom rule to check if the content-type is multipart/form-data* using regex.

We have set that custom rule with higher priority. When using the custom rule the images are uploaded but the script tags are not forbidden. Without having the custom rule if we try uploading the images one particular image alone is not getting uploaded and throws 403 forbidden.

Any hints on adding XSS and custom rule to allow image uploads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced 403 issue in AWS firewall when I try to add image as multipart/form-data.

Some of the WAF rules which blocks the image upload are,  AWS#AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet#SQLi_BODY,
AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet#GenericRFI_BODY, and AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet#CrossSiteScripting_BODY.

I solved this issue by uploading the image as base64 string instead of uploading as multipart/form-data.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue while uploading images to s3 via a PHP form submission. I'm using the default WAF rule script provided by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/aws-waf-security-automations/template.html.      Let me check with the developer regarding the image upload encryption.

Comment: It's a pretty good approach. But you'll have problems with SizeBody of the same set of rules on WAF.

Comment: Uploading as base64 is, in general, not a great idea. It makes the request bigger and multipart/form-data is specifically for situations like this.

Comment: GenericRFI_BODY is actually part of AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet

Answer (score 12):

Check your image metadata. I recently encountered this issue, and was getting the "GenericRFI_BODY" error in the ACL logs. It turns out the test image I was uploading had an illegal path in its exif data. There was a URL that pointed to the site where the image came from in some metadata field, and the "://" pattern in that URL was triggering the rule. Stripping the metadata from the image allowed it to upload.

I strongly discourage base64 encoding to circumvent firewall rules. This will bloat the size of your files, and multipart/form-data exists specifically to stream large binaries back and forth from client to server - not to post massive serialized text blocks.

Here's the RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

Comment: This is likely the proper answer.

Answer (score 9):

Goto your Web ACL and click on edit **AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet** and make **Override rules action** to **True** for rule **SizeRestrictions_BODY**

Comment: This approach definitely doesn't solve the problem. This is a bypass check that the WAF does.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my issue
Goto your Web ACL and click on edit AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet and make Override rules action to True for rule SizeRestrictions_BODY

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to the following WAF rule:

```
ruleGroupList.0.ruleGroupId             AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet
ruleGroupList.0.terminatingRule.ruleId  SizeRestrictions_BODY
```

And I solved the problem by overriding the default rule action from `BLOCK` to `CHALLENGE`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a 403 Forbidden error when trying to upload files as multipart/form-data and I solved it by following the instructions on this [aws article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/waf-explicit-allow-file-uploads) Basically you need to add a new WAF rule with a higher priority than the one that is blocking you (in my case it was SizeRestrictions_BODY)