HTTP 403 response when uploading file to AWS hosted ASP.NET Core App
I have an ASP.NET Core C# web application hosted in an ECS container on AWS, sitting behind an ELB/WAF.
I'm trying to POST a file to a controller action:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey")]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    [HttpPost("Upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] IFormFile data)
    {
        ...
    }

But when I make a request (using curl as an example):
curl -X POST -v -F "data=@D:\TEST_FILE.zip" -H "API-KEY: ****" https://example.com/api/Data/Upload 

I get an HTTP 403 response from the AWS ELB:
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: awselb/2.0
< Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2024 12:42:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 118
< Connection: keep-alive

A few things:

Lack of application logs on AWS server indicate the request never reached the app.
All other requests in the app are fine, the issue is only on the file upload request.
This is not and upload to S3, just to the application.

How can I further troubleshoot what's stopping this request?

You mentioned you have a WAF attached to your load balancer, so that's probably the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853122/aws-waf-getting-403-forbidden-error-while-trying-to-upload-an-image You should go to your WAF's dashboard and see if there are rejected requests listed there, to verify that is the issue.

Yes! I see the rejected request in the WAF logs coming from AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet rule SizeRestrictions_BODY.  So that makes sense why only the file upload is being blocked.
